# vertically center link in li

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

This is supposed to be a horizontal menu bar. I'm struggling to vertically center the text. Any advice?

```
<ul id="header-menu">
    <li id="header-logo"></li>
    <li id="header-v-space"></li>
    <li id="header-menu">
        <a href="/discover">
            <strong>Discover</strong><span>great things</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="header-v-space"></li>
    <li id="header-menu">
        <a href="/share">
            <strong>Share</strong><span>opportunities</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id="header-v-space"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: weird spacing is from my poor stack overflow code formatting

Comment: Also - how should I work the css so both the background of the li's and the text color for these menu options both change. at present I can only get the background to change using #header-menu a:hover,a:active
{
background-image:url(../images/header_bg_select.png);
}

Comment: What about showing us your CSS?

Comment: @stopshinal: Formatting fixed

Answer (score 2):

I normally got these results by specifying a `height` which is identical to the `line-height` while setting the top- and bottom-padding to zero.

```
li {
    padding: 0 .5em;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em; }
```